# Почему люди зашиваются?

Tags: фразеология

Когда у человека очень много работы и он ничего не успевает, он говорит, что "зашивается". Интересно, а откуда пошло это выражение? Почему он именно зашивается - вроде как, шитье - не самое торопливое и многотрудное занятие?
Или происхождение этой поговорки вообще не связано с портняжным делом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ЗАШИТЬСЯ,  Разг. Делая многое, не успеть выполнить, сделать всё, что нужно. З. с делами. З. на работе.

Зашиться, замотаться - у этих глаголов примерно одинаковые значения. Человек суетится, бегает туда-сюда, что очень похоже на движение иголки с ниткой при шитье или на сматывание ниток.

Формант ЗА...СЯ имеет значение доведения действия до крайних пределов (забегаться, заиграться, зачитаться).

Comment: Спасибо за лингвистический концепт "за...ся", он реально многое объясняет! Действительно, вставь туда любое слово и получается крайний предел

Answer (score 2):

Можно предположить следующее. Не справляясь с работой, человек начинает суетиться и попросту *затыкать дыры* - где больше рвется. Это напоминает действия портного, который ставит заплату на заплате, без особого успеха.

> Илья Ильф, Евгений Петров. Золотой теленок (1931)
> И ведь сам знает, что зашился, хочет выкарабкаться, но такое сам нагромоздил, что не может.
> (Нацкорпус)

Comment: Большое спасибо за цитату из великолепной книги! Значит действительно с тех пор идёт...

Answer (score 0):

Выполняя долгое время такую монотонную работу, как шитьё, человек может потерять бдительность, стать небрежным и нечаянно пришить свою собственную одежду к работе - придётся переделывать: и время, и усилия насмарку! Или даже может ткнуть иглой себе в палец, пораниться, "пришить" себя к ткани. Если приходится шить очень быстро, то вероятность таких происшествий возрастает.

Comment: сомнительное объяснение если подумать, что альтернативных способов придумать как сказать очень много, но почему-то популярным стало именно от "шить"